# JLabel not visible on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm working on a program in which I'd used a `JTextArea`, `JButton`, `JLabel` and `JPanel`.
The logic I'd to implement is: user types a text in the given `textArea` and then click on the `button`. On button click I'd to retrieve the text from the `textArea` and create a `label` with the written text(as in `textArea`) and show it on the `panel`.
Everything I'd done previously is correct but the problem is with the `label` and `panel`. The `label` is not visible on the `panel`.

The code snippets is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author mohammadfaisal
 * http://ermohammadfaisal.blogspot.com
 * http://facebook.com/m.faisal6621
 * 
 */
public class CodeMagnets extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea area4Label;
    private JLabel codeLabel;
    private JButton createButton;
    private JPanel magnet;

    public CodeMagnets(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        magnet=new JPanel(null);
        JScrollPane magnetScroller=new JScrollPane(magnet);
              magnetScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        magnetScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, magnetScroller);
        JPanel inputPanel=new JPanel();
        area4Label=new JTextArea(5, 30);
        area4Label.setTabSize(4);
        JScrollPane textScroller=new JScrollPane(area4Label);
        inputPanel.add(textScroller);
        createButton=new JButton("Create code magnet");
        createButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //codeLabel=new JLabel(area4Label.getText());
                codeLabel=new MyLabel(area4Label.getText());//this is for my new question
                codeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
                codeLabel.setLocation(50, 20);
                codeLabel.setVisible(true);
                magnet.add(codeLabel);
                area4Label.setText("");
                //pack();
            }
        });
        inputPanel.add(createButton);
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, inputPanel);
        //pack();
        setSize(640, 480);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CodeMagnets("Code Magnets");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to repaint()/validate() your panle after adding new components in it dynamically. So after this:

```
magnet.add(codeLabel);
```

add this:

```
magnet.validate();
```

or

```
magnet.repaint();
```

---

Also one thing you are using null layout for magnet panel. So must have to setBounds() of jLable before adding it to magnet panel. So it becomes

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    codeLabel=new JLabel(area4Label.getText());
    codeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    codeLabel.setBounds(50, 20, 100, 100);
    magnet.add(codeLabel);
    magnet.repaint();
    area4Label.setText("");
}
```

It is not recommended to use `null` as layout, you should use proper layout like BorderLayout or GridLayout or even simpler FlowLayout based on your requirement.

---

As said by @Andrew use something like:

```
codeLabel.setSize(codeLabel.getPreferredSize());
codeLabel.setLocation(50, 20);
```

instead of

```
codeLabel.setBounds(50, 20, 100, 100);
```

This will solve the size issue of jLabel.

Comment: added `magnet.validate()` but still not working. Neither `reapint()` nor `validate()` is working.  I'd to make the `label` visible on the `panel`.

Comment: I'd used `setLocation()` does it now enough because `setBounds()` may trim the text. `setBounds()` also not working. I request you to please check the code by executing.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: No. When you use `null` in layout you **must** explicitly define bounds of a component.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If he will not specify bounds for a null layout the component will never come into the picture. Isn't this right?

Comment: Isn't any way out, because it trims my text.
the user can enter any number of lines.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: Use some layout.

Comment: Actually I want these `label`s draggable, therefore I'd `setLayout(null)`

Comment: OK - I think the `null` layout should be swapped out for a custom layout, but my main objection to the answer was that `setBounds()` is so much guesswork as to the **size** of the component.  It would be better (even when using a `null` layout) to set it to the preferred size then call `setLocation()` rather than `setBounds()`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: `setLocation()` is not working. I'd forcefully have to use `setBounds()`. Can I get the preferred size after using the `setBounds()`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: hmm... now I get it. Mohammad Faisal: instead of setBounds() use setSize(getPreferedSize()) and setLocation(); This might work for you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I have updated the answer. Is it right for now?

Comment: *"Is it right for now?"*   Gets an up-vote here.  Good call on the edit. :)

Comment: setbounds is the preferred way when u want to update the element, f.e. when the size of parent JFrame changes. u will have to work with percentual numbers or a clever calculation of getDimension()

Answer (score -1):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
codeLabel=new JLabel(area4Label.getText());
codeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
codeLabel.setBounds(50, 20, 100, 100);
codeLabel.setOpaque(True);
magnet.add(codeLabel);
magnet.repaint();
area4Label.setText("");
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).