# Why instance of JLabel shows only 8 lines?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

> **Exact Duplicate and Good answer is there:**
>   [Why instance of JLabel shows only 8 lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347014/why-instance-of-jlabel-shows-only-8-lines)

I'd a code snippet:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author mohammadfaisal
 * http://ermohammadfaisal.blogspot.com
 * http://facebook.com/m.faisal6621
 * 
 */
public class CodeMagnets extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea area4Label;
    private JLabel codeLabel;
    private JButton createButton;
    private JPanel magnet;

    public CodeMagnets(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        magnet=new JPanel(null);
        JScrollPane magnetScroller=new JScrollPane(magnet);
              magnetScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        magnetScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, magnetScroller);
        JPanel inputPanel=new JPanel();
        area4Label=new JTextArea(5, 30);
        area4Label.setTabSize(4);
        JScrollPane textScroller=new JScrollPane(area4Label);
        inputPanel.add(textScroller);
        createButton=new JButton("Create code magnet");
        createButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //codeLabel=new JLabel(area4Label.getText());
                codeLabel=new MyLabel(area4Label.getText());//this is for my new question
                codeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
                codeLabel.setLocation(50, 20);
                codeLabel.setVisible(true);
                magnet.add(codeLabel);
                area4Label.setText("");
                //pack();
            }
        });
        inputPanel.add(createButton);
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, inputPanel);
        //pack();
        setSize(640, 480);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CodeMagnets("Code Magnets");
    }
}


class MyLabel extends JLabel{
    MyLabel(String text){
        super(text);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }

    public static void main(String...args){
         String text="<html>"
                     +"1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>"
                     +"</html>";//this is the text which is typed in the text box by the user for creating a label
    }
}
```

Here the label created shows only `8` lines properly and the border in enough longer than needed(I need a `label` with a border covering its boundary but not such a way).

Can anybody help me to make more lines visible(do not suggest to use `ScrollPane` because my intension is not that) and create a border exactly rigid to the text?

please check this question also to be more clear what i want:

[JLabel not visible on Jpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339790/jlabel-not-visible-on-jpanel)

Comment: http://forum.codecall.net/java-help/16048-dynamically-growing-jlabel-text-size.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use setSize at all!

Instead add the component to the JFrame's contentPane, call `pack()` on the JFrame, then call `setVisible(true)`. This way you let the Swing layout managers decide how to size everything so that components are optimally shown.

Answer (score 1):

Not used JLabel in a while but I'm sure you can call setSize on it - would this do what you like?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking that the border should be around `MyLabel` component?
If yes, try another layout like: `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

If you want frame to contain no extra space, use `frame.pack();`